# Simulator overload in Xcode 13.3 (13E113)

Tags: xcode, simulator

[image]

When launching Xcode today, I was prompted that additional components needed to be installed. Had no other choice but to accept and man did I get more than I bargained for! The list goes on an on, next is the iPad Air (5th generation) with just as many and so on.

So far I have relaunched Xcode and the simulator, but to no avail.

Any one else experiencing this?

**Update:**

I did go ahead trying to delete all the simulators, believing that a later install would solve the problem. I used this command at the terminal to delete them:

```
xcrun simctl delete all
```

Then, I downloaded simulators for iOS 15.0 and 15.2.
After this I had no simulators to select. So the problem goes from simulator bonanza to no simulators at all.

Then I uninstalled Xcode and emptied the trash can.
Hours later, Xcode was finally installed and I still have no simulators. As a bonus, the option to download simulators is now gone! This is getting frustrating.

Comment: I’d suggest taking a look at “Window” » “Devices and Simulators” » “Simulators” and see what you see there. But I’m personally not seeing the behavior you describe…

Comment: Thanks Rob, but sadly the list is empty. What I see is the text "No selection", then nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. If anyone having the same issue, this is what I worked for me.

1. Deleted the simulators using the command:
   xcrun simctl delete all
2. Selected the menu item "Add additional simulators".
3. Then at the bottom left corner in the "Simulators" dialog, pressed the pluss sign "+".
4. Selected the appropriate device types and OS versions from the popup and created the few simulators I needed.

All the clutter is now gone ("simulator" (GUID))...
And I am back having the few I need.